# Refering to view values one by one

Tags: c#, .net, sqldatareader, sqlcommand, sql-view

I have the following code which establishing an SQL connection inside of a project I am working on.  What I want to do is to create a `for` loop which contains a method and every time the loop repeats the method runs with a different value until all views of the returned query are used.

I can't figure out how to refer to every value of the view without saving the view to a list or an array first.  Any ideas?

```
SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost\**;Initial Catalog=ML;User Id=sa;Password='**'");
string sql = @"select product_id,Name from E_PRODUCT_PROPERTY";
var mylist = new List<WineRating>();
using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, Con))
{
    Con.Open();
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
            new WineRating { product_id = reader.GetInt32(0), Name = reader.GetString(1) };                    

///Here goes the code I suppose

        method_name(reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1));

    }
}

public static int method_name(int product_id, string Name)
{
int num = x *2;
Console.WriteLine(num + Name);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to filter the data in the database using a 'WHERE' clause? or do you want to save the values in a dictionary and access them via a 'KEY'?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.  The same way you access members of the current result record (or, if you want to access the columns by name, using [the indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.item) or [`GetOrdinal()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getordinal)) to initialize `new WineRating` is the same way you would access those members to build text for `Console.WriteLine()` to print.  You'd use a `while` loop just like you've done, not a `for` loop.

Comment: What I actually want is to pass every record of the view into a method one by one but I dont understand how to do that.Can you give me an example of how to reffer every record in a loop and pass them to a method one record each time a loop repeats?

Comment: Thanks I edited my question maybe now its more clear, as soon as I am able to try It I will run your code and tell you feedback

Comment: Hi again It is not working for some reason,are you sure it is right?

Comment: If these comments are in response to [@Barns's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61966594/150605) you should post them on that answer so that user will be notified of them.  You should probably elaborate on "It is not working", too.

Comment: If the edited code above reflects the code you are testing then, no...it can't work. Because you did not follow the code example I provided! --You did notice the Curly Brackets? They aren't just pretty...they have a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps like this:

```
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        MyMethodToPrintToScreen(reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1));
    }
}
```

With the method to print to screen

```
private static void MyMethodToPrintToScreen(int id, string product)
{
    //Do whatever you wish with the data: example
    Console.WriteLine($"My id: {id} | Product: {product}");
}
```

---

**Edit**
Let me make it even more obvious(using your exact code):

```
SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost\**;Initial Catalog=ML;User Id=sa;Password='**'");
string sql = @"select product_id,Name from E_PRODUCT_PROPERTY";
var mylist = new List<WineRating>();
using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, Con))
{
    Con.Open();
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            method_name(reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you are the best